# MySQL - Key Column Doesn't Exist in Table

Tags: mysql

I'm having what I hope is a simple problem - in running a Select statement to join multiple tables together, I'm getting the following error: 'Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table'

Very rarely the query will successfully complete as a preview, but fails each time it's run as a job. I'm easing into SQL for analysis, so I apologize if I'm overlooking something blindingly obvious.

```
SELECT `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`id` AS 'Blossom CI'
, `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`name` AS 'Blossom Name'
, `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`regulatory_impact` AS 'Compliance Obligation'
, `GCPID`
, `GCP_CI`
, `GCP_App`
, `GCP_Project`
, `GCP_Instance`
, `TAP Name`
, `TAP_CI`
, `Cluster0Environ`
, `Cluster1Environ`
, `OpenStack CI`
, `OpenStack Name`
, `OpenStack UUID`
, `instances.0.display_name`
, `VMAAS Name`
, `VMAAS CI`
, `VMAAS Environ`
, `VMAAS Owner`
FROM `itse_blossom_applications_view`
  LEFT JOIN `gcp_normalized` ON `gcp_normalized`.`GCP_CI` = `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `tap_cleaned_inventory` ON `tap_cleaned_inventory`.`TAP_CI` = `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `openstack_renamed_inventory` ON `openstack_renamed_inventory`.`OpenStack CI` = `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `vmaas_normalized` ON `vmaas_normalized`.`VMAAS CI` = `itse_blossom_applications_view`.`id`
WHERE
  `GCP_CI` IS NOT NULL
  OR `TAP_CI` IS NOT NULL
  OR `OpenStack CI` IS NOT NULL
  OR `VMAAS CI` IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY `TAP Name`
, `GCPID`
, `OpenStack Name`
, `VMAAS Name`
```

The source data are relatively small tables (2k - 20k rows) which are normalized (Capitalizing/Trimming/Removing Nulls/Empties on certain columns) prior to being ingested into the MYSQL database.

Comment: I suggest you enable `ANSI_QUOTES` and dispense with all those silly backticks and case-sensitive column names with spaces in them. Unless, of course, you want to dedicate the rest of your life to chasing typos.

Comment: Please qualify each column; to understand the query, we need to know which column is in which table.  Are you using `VIEWs`?  If so, we need to see `SHOW CREATE VIEW`, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.